# Google+ Share link / Send message to pre-filled users

Tags: google-plus, share, message

I am building a web application using google+ login.
My users can select people in their circles to invite them on app events.

I would like my users to be able to share the event link or to send it via message to the users they have selected (I just have their ids...) without having to type again every name in the share dialog.

It's possible with Facebook API so I tough it would be possible with g+ but I didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question ;

With interactive post, it's possible to specify data-recipients as well as data-prefilltext.

More informations on [google specific documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#interactive_share_button_attributes)